# Multiple open source git repos as sub folders

Tags: git, github

I am an open source developer and I often rely on third party components for my work. I dont mind getting updated automatically. Optionally I would prefer working with tags of those third party repos.

How do I get the following structure in my git repo without having to commit the work my self.

|- Folder 1
|- Folder 2
|- Folder 3
|       |- git repo 1
|- git repo 2
|- git repo 3 [ tag v 1.0.0 ]

Answer (score 1):

If you really want/need to have the raw source code of these third-party projects on the same repository as your own project, then you can use [Git Submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), or something similar, such as [Git Subtree](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt), or [Repo](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/), for example.

However, it is much more common nowadays to take dependencies on packages produced by the maintainers of the open-source projects, which you reference in your project, and manage through a package manager, such as [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) (mainly for .NET apps), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) (mainly for Javascript apps), etc.

You can see a list with some popular package managers here:
https://github.com/showcases/package-managers

This has the benefit that you don't have to store the source code together with your own code (you also don't need to store the package, unless you want to), and is also meant to be much easier to integrate with your source code, given that these packages are made on purpose to be consumed by other projects.